# how to send multiple email pick from database in php

Tags: php, email, sendmail

hi i want to send multiple email which are registered user and info has been saved in database so here i juz want to send email using php scripts.

here is my code

```
                <?php
            //Connect to database
            $sql = "SELECT email FROM TABLENAME";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
            {
            $area = $row['email']. ", ";
            // read the list of emails from the file.
            $email_list = $area;
            // count how many emails there are.
            $total_emails = count($email_list);
            // go through the list and trim off the newline character.
            for ($counter=0; $counter<$total_emails; $counter++) {
            $email_list[$counter] = trim($email_list[$counter]);
            }
            $to = $email_list;
            echo $to;
            }
            if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
            //if "email" is filled out, send email
            {
            //send email
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
            $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
            mail( "newsletter@mydomain.com", "Subject: $subject",
            $message, "From: $email" );
            echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
            }
            else
            //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
            {
            echo "<form method='post' action=''>
            Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' class='xl' /><br />
            Message: <textarea name='message' cols='20' rows='10'></textarea><br />
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Send' />
            </form>";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: On every loop, `$email_list = $area;` will get overwritten. `count` is used for arrays and not strings

Comment: You're treating `$email_list` as an array, but it's just a copy of the `$area` string. Did you mean `$email_list = explode(', ', $area);`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, as in code you have written -

> mail( "newsletter@mydomain.com", "Subject: $subject",
>               $message, "From: $email" );
>   in above code block first parameter should be the the list you have created with name as $area.

Anyway in my opinion you should give a try to [mail_queue](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-queue.php) lib once.